# How to force Bluetooth LE "Just Works" Pairing in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have an embedded system running a GATT server that I am trying to connect to via Android. The task is simple: connect to the GATT server, navigate characteristics, and validate read/write capabilities. The problem is when I try and connect with an Android app, it attempts to pair with a "Passkey" instead of with "Just Works" [https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/LE-Security.aspx]. This isn't acceptable as my embedded device does not have any method of displaying a key to the user to use for pairing. So the connection method must be Just Works.

I have tried numerous apps from the Play store and all of them only attempt to pair with Passkey. But this is the current one I am working with: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner

I have this working using the LightBlue application (supported in OS X and iOS). So I know my peripheral (GATT server) is working: advertising, connectable, characteristic accessible, etc.

How do I force Android to use Just Works instead of Passkey pairing? Is there a peripheral configuration I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Your embedded device should be advertising an appropriate IO capability during the bluetooth authentication phase. In particular it should probably be advertsing NoInpiutOutput. How to do this depends on what you are running on your embedded system. If you are running Linux for example then the agent that comes with bluez can be run thus: test-agent -c NoInputNoOutput

Comment: @kaylum What is **test-agent**, is it a command?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky test-agent is the example agent code that comes with bluez. It's been renamed `simple-agent`. Source code [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/simple-agent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of the issue was the mode the Linux interface was in. Bluetooth devices that support both BR/EDR (Classic) and LE by default are in dual-mode. That is, they can operate as a Classic or LE device. I do not have insight into the Android API and have not attempted to develop an Android app that can detect a dual-mode device and choose to connect as LE using Just Working pairing. But I was able to disable BR/EDR on the interface and validate Android detected it during scan as an LE only (single-mode) interface. The Android app then connected seamlessly using Just Working pairing.

Here is how I disabled BR/EDR on the interface:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 down
$ sudo ./btmgmt bredr off
hci0 Set BR/EDR complete, settings: connectable bondable le 
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv
```

You can build the btmgmt application in Linux by downloading and building Bluez. The btmgmt application is built conditionally on the `--enable-experimental` config parameter.

**UPDATE:**
Another approach is instead of modifying the interface capabilities, just modify the broadcasted interface capabilities. This is done through the advertisement flags. Modify the flags to broadcast that BR/EDR is not supported. This is bit 2 and would creates a flags broadcast of 0x04. (See Bluetooth SIG doc CSS v4: Part A, Section 1.3.2)

Comment: Glad you got it working. But not sure the explanation quite makes sense. Because classic bluetooth also supports Just Works Pairing. It sounds like perhaps the problem was shifted rather than solved.

Comment: It isn't a matter of BR/EDR supporting Just Works. I'm working with Play Store Android apps that are defaulting to Passkey pairing. The only way I can get them to work is if the interface is in single-mode (LE only). It is likely that it is possible to control this with Android's API as I don't have the same issues with iOS apps. But I was just tasked with the embedded side of things. And as this will be an LE-only device. It makes sense to advertise that BR/EDR is not supported.

Comment: By "Modify the flags to broadcast that BR/EDR is not supported", did you mean modify them on remote device or android? Was this fix on android side?

Comment: @GPS  According to the commands above, they are executed on the server (remote device) running Linux.

Comment: @linsek Do u know how to modify the broadcasted interface capabilities?